# Why vsock is using 32 bit port number instead of 16 bit?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm

While reading vsock specification I came across below quote

> A socket address is defined as a combination of a 32-bit Context
>   Identifier (CID) and a 32-bit port number.

source: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vsock.7.html

I thought we cannot use a port number higher than 65535 as it is a 16-bit value. Does anyone know why vsock is using 32-bit port number? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with this feature but after reading that man page my guess is that it does sound very much like TCP and UDP but is not the same. Thus the TCP/UDP port limit does not apply. The address family for TCP and UDP is `AF_INET`.

Answer (score 1):

In Berkeley Sockets, the concept of a "port number" has always been specific to a particular address family. `AF_INET` (IPv4) and `AF_INET6` (IPv6) both use 16-bit port numbers, because that is the standard for the TCP/IP protocol stack. Port numbers belong to the transport layer protocol (TCP/UDP/SCTP/DCCP/etc), not the network layer (IP); while in principle there is nothing stopping someone from running a transport protocol over an IP network which uses non-16-bit port numbers (8-bit port numbers, 32-bit port numbers, variable length port numbers, no concept of port numbers at all), in practice every widely-used transport protocol which runs directly over IP uses 16-bit ports. If someone wanted to add support for an unusual IP-based protocol with non-16-bit port numbers to Berkeley Sockets, they might not be able to use the standard address families (`AF_INET`,`AF_INET6`) with a custom protocol number (`IPPROTO_WHATEVER`), they'd likely have to define a custom address family instead (well, there are hacky ways to avoid doing that, but those hacks are probably not a good idea.)

But although `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6` both have 16-bit port numbers, many other address families don't. The definition of `struct sockaddr` is up to each address family. Some other address families have port numbers, some have an equivalent concept with a different name, some have no real equivalent. And among those which have port numbers (or equivalent), there is no requirement they must be 16-bit.

For example, `AF_IB` (Infiniband) doesn't have port numbers as such, but the approximate equivalent is Service IDs – which are 64-bit. Like TCP/IP, `AF_IPX` used 16-bit port numbers (although Linux dropped IPX support in 4.18 and SPX support long before that.) `AF_X25` has no concept of port numbers at all, only network addresses (X.121); the only way to support multiple services over X.25 is to assign the host multiple X.121 network addresses (one per a service), or else use some application-level multiplexing above the Berkeley Sockets layer. `AF_ISO` (sometimes also called `AF_OSI`), the legacy OSI TP transport protocol (X.224 / ISO 8073), even allows port numbers (TSAPs) to have a variable number of bytes, although a widely-followed US government standard (GOSIP / FIPS 146) mandated 2 byte TSAPs (so 16-bits just like TCP/IP or IPX/SPX). (`AF_ISO`/`AF_OSI` was never in mainline Linux, but was included in 4.4BSD, some commercial Unixes, and some mainframe/minicomputer operating systems; note very recent Linux kernels now have a `struct sockaddr_iso`, but that's got nothing to do with the legacy OSI protocol stack, that's actually for isochronous Bluetooth addresses.)

TIPC (Transparent Inter Process Communication) is a protocol designed for communication between nodes in computer clusters, with support included in the Linux kernel. TIPC can run over UDP/IP, or directly over Ethernet or Infiniband. And TIPC (`AF_TIPC`, `struct sockaddr_tipc`) has 32-bit port numbers. If you are running it over UDP, the 32-bit TIPC port number has no relationship with the 16-bit UDP port number; the UDP port numbers are determined when the system administrator configures UDP links between nodes in the cluster, and are invisible to applications using `AF_TIPC` sockets.

Coming to `AF_VSOCK`, VSOCK is a protocol designed for communication between the software running in a virtual machine and the hypervisor under which it runs. Since it only runs on a single machine, as opposed to over a network protocol such as IP, there is no strong reason to limit port numbers to 16-bits. On a 32-bit architecture, 16-bit values tend to perform worse than 32-bit values, unless you pad them to 32-bit; since for good performance it must be padded to 32-bits, you might as well make it 32-bits to begin with. While the same logic might lead you to make them 64-bit for the sake of 64-bit architectures, that gives worse performance on 32-bit platforms, which were much more significant when VSOCK was designed than they are now; 32-bit ports are likely enough for everyone, and the marginal benefits of 64-bit port numbers don't outweigh the performance drawback for 32-bit platforms.

Note `AF_VSOCK` is not the only address family in the Linux kernel for VM-hypervisor communication. VSOCK was invented by VMware, but has since been copied by other vendors, including KVM, QEMU and Microsoft Hyper-V. IBM's z/VM hypervisor (used on mainframes) doesn't use VSOCK, it has its own protocol called IUCV which performs the same function. IUCV is a lot older than VSOCK–VMware introduced VSOCK in 2008; IBM released the first version of IUCV in *1980*. From what I recall, the Linux kernel dev team made clear to everyone they didn't want every separate VM vendor defining their own address family for VM-hypervisor communication, and hence everyone else had to use the `AF_VSOCK` invented by VMware; IBM was exempted from that rule since their IUCV protocol long predates VMware's, with completely incompatible addressing.

Rather than using numeric port numbers, `AF_IUCV` addresses (`struct sockaddr_iucv`) are based on 8-byte space-padded human-readable character strings (in EBCDIC, although under Linux they are ASCII in userspace, the ASCII/EBCDIC conversion happens inside the kernel.) That said, `sockaddr_iucv` actually has a 32-bit address number and 16-bit port number field at the start of it, which are reserved and always set to 0. You'll find that on Linux, but Linux copied those reserved fields from IBM's mainframe operating systems (such as CMS and z/OS), which do the same thing in their Berkeley Sockets IUCV implementations. I suspect the reason why IBM did that, was to reduce bugs if you accidentally passed a `sockaddr_iucv` to an application/library which was expecting only a `sockaddr_in` (`AF_INET`, IPv4) – it would then get interpreted as `0.0.0.0:0`, which causes less (and more predictable) harm than trying to interpret an arbitrary string as an IPv4 address and port.